# Expose K8s POD to single/range of External IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, kubernetes

We would like to expose our `POD` to external IP. If we would use `AWS LB` then it will be available to the public. Are there any alternative solutions?

Here is what I did so far:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "testing"
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [{
      "port": 80,
      "targetPort": 8080
    }],
    "selector": {
      "app": "testing"
    },
    "type": "LoadBalancer"
  }
}
```

We like to expose it to only a single IP or a range of external IPs.

Comment: What are your attempts before asking this question ? please share them

Comment: Edited my comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.spec.loadBalancerSourceRanges` key, as documented in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-for-loadbalancer-service):

> This field takes a list of IP CIDR ranges, which Kubernetes will use to configure firewall exceptions. This feature is currently supported on Google Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service, Azure Kubernetes Service, and IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) abstraction of kubernetes and use nginx ingress controller as an implementation of that.Nginx provides [whitelisting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range) of source IP range.

[AWS ALB ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/guide/ingress/annotation.md#inbound-cidrs) has a annotation `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs` which does provide the same feature.

Comment: Is there no way to fulfill by using k8s ingress or AWS ALB ingress ?

e.g

alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: external IP/24